# How can I make a paged ListView?

Tags: c#, mvvm, microsoft-metro

I have a long list of items, and I need to display them in a ListView. I then need the pages to rotate automatically using a timer. What do?

Comment: Is it metro or WPF?  It can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Windows 8-style UI/ Metro app)

In your View: add {Binding PagedItems} to the ItemSource property of your ListView.

In your ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public ObservableCollection<Item> PagedItems {get;set;}
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _itemsToPage;
    private int _itemsPerPage;
    private int _currentPage;

    public ViewModel() {
        _itemsToPage = new ObservableCollection<Item>(); // replace this with whatever your items are

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,10)};
        _timer.Tick += NextPage;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void NextPage(object sender, object e) {
        if (_itemsToPage < _itemsPerPage) return;

        if (_currentPage * _itemsPerPage >= _itemsToPage) _currentPage = 1;
        else _currentPage++;

        // the key line
        PagedItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(
            _itemsToPage.Skip((_currentPage-1) * _itemsPerPage)
                .Take(_itemsPerPage));

        OnPropertyChanged("PagedItems") // you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

The basic idea: every x seconds create a new list based on a subset of the items from the list you want to page. You'll notice `(_currentPage-1) * _itemsPerPage` is the element number of the first item on each page.

Comment: Actually, answering your own questions [is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @DanJ of course, but I somehow doubt that asking a question and immediately posting an answer to it is a way to go. Anyway, I digress, problem seems to be solved. :)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor - click on the ask question button and note the message at the bottom! I only posted because I spent a while yesterday doing it and I thought it was a neat way of sharing.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor - click on the ask question button and note the message at the bottom! I only posted because I spent a while yesterday doing it and I thought it was a neat way of sharing.